# How do I resolve VMware Airwatch enrollment issue on android?

Tags: vmware, mdm, airwatch

Airwatch stuck on enrollment process repeatedly within Android devices.. Horrible experience and does not work correctly for users with Samsung workplace services. Their support line  has not been of any help either.  Are there any users with similar experiences? No issues with iPhone using native mail client or Boxer.

Comment: Can you explain your set up more? Is it a corporate owned device? How are you provisioning? What are you pushing to the phone? Two things to try if provisioning Airwatch as device owner (via NFC or QR code): 1. Keep system apps enabled (there is a toggle in Airwatch's NFC app) 2. Set "Encrypt Device" to false, devices Marshmallow and later will already be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

We have both iOS and Android devices. For Android we use only Samsung (both tablets and smartphones, usually Galaxy A3 and A5, but also S6 and higher) and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable this setting to Enroll Android devices in **Airwatch** admin console

**Groups & Settings --> All Settings**

[image]